# Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Path not found

Tags: vbscript

I want to execute a vbs script which provides me the size of a given folder but at the execution it returns me the error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Path not found

Previously, the error was

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied

but after these commands:

```
takeown /f C:\Users /r /d y                          
icacls C:\Users /grant administrators:F /T
```

it turned into "path not found". As you can see the folder that I want the size is `C:\Users`.

Here's my code:

```
'Created the 18.03.2010
'Easy script for check space folder. You need NRPE_NT daemon on win computer
'##########################################################'
'Install'
'##########################################################'
'1.copy file to c:\ for example... c:\nrpe_nt\bin\check_folder_size.vbs'
'2.set your nrpe.cfg for command for example 
'command[check_foldersize]=c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //NoLogo //T:30 c:\nrpe_nt\bin\check_folder_size.vbs c:\yourfolder 50 78
'50 70 are parameters for warning and critical value in MB'
'3.restart your nrpe_nt daemon in command prompt example.. net stop nrpe_nt and net start nrpe_nt'
'4. try from linux example.: ./check_nrpe -H yourcomputer -c check_foldersize and result can be OK:22,8 MB'
'it is all'
'##########################################################'
Dim strfolder
Dim intwarning
Dim intcritic
Dim wsh
Dim intvelkost
Dim intjednotka
'##########################################################'
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'##########################################################'
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 3 Then
  strfolder  = WScript.Arguments(0)
  intwarning = WScript.Arguments(1)
  intcritic  = WScript.Arguments(2)

  Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strfolder)
  intjednotka = 1048576 '1MB->bytes'
  intvelkost = objFolder.Size/intjednotka

  If (objFolder.Size/1048576) > CInt(intwarning) Then  
    WScript.Echo "WARNING:" & round (objFolder.Size / 1048576,1) & " MB"
    WScript.Quit(1)
  ElseIf (objFolder.Size/1024000) > CInt(intcritic) Then  
    WScript.Echo "CRITICAL:" & Round(objFolder.Size / 1048576,1) & " MB"
    WScript.Quit(2)
  Else
    WScript.Echo "OK:" & Round(objFolder.Size /1048576,1) & " MB"
    WScript.Quit(0)
  End If
Else
  WScript.Echo "UNKNOWN:"& strfolder &"-" & intwarning & "-" & intcritic
  WScript.Quit(3)
End If
```

The line of the call of the script:

```
check_foldersize = cscript.exe //nologo //T:60 scripts\check_folder_size.vbs C:\Users 4000 5000
```

Edit: One more useful point : There are no errors when I change the folder C:\Users to C:\Intel for example. So it seems to be a problem linked to the Users folder itself. Then I don't think that iis_iusrs permissions are the cause.

Comment: You mention `iis_iusrs` security group, is this a [tag:asp-classic] Web Application? If so, it should be tagged accordingly in the question. At the moment the information you provide is a bit contradictory, i.e you're executing the script using `cscript.exe` but talking about `iis_iusr` permissions?

Comment: The `%SystemDrive%\Users` folder is a system folder and as such will probably require elevated permissions to access it, UAC strikes again!

Comment: @Lankymart Someone answered me by saying that it was maybe iis_iusr permissions

Comment: Ok, in which case they assumed you were developing a Web Application in Classic ASP *(which uses VBScript by default)*. From what I can see here though you are calling the script direct from `cscript.exe` so none of that is relevant. What is relevant, however, is it is likely to be a permissions issue like I mentioned above. That folder is deemed a System Folder so UAC is probably going to more stringent about who can access it programmatically. Can you try running the script through an elevated command prompt as a test?